# How to set up and use Multi-Touch Event in cocos2d x V 2.2.3 C++ complete simple example?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, multi-touch

I want to use multi touch functionality. I am using Xcode 5.0.2 with cocos2dx v2.2.3
I have tried a lot but unsuccessful to perform multitouch.
I found the tutorial of cocos2d x V.3.0 but the following line is not working for v2.2.3

```
 auto listener =  EventListenerTouchAllAtOnce::create();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are using is `Cocos2d-x v3`. Upgrade and you can use it.

For `Cocos2d-x v2.2.3` you would need to look at `CCTargetedTouchDelegate`

An example for 2.2.3 can be found here: http://paralaxer.com/touch-tutorial-player-movement/

Comment: could you please provide sam sample code for multi-touch event for cocos2d-x v2.2.3 ?

Comment: Thanks it helped me a lot. I have solved my problem by the example provided by you. :)